# Find the measure of the external angle bisector $A$ of a triangle $ABC$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:  Calculate the measure of the exterior bisector
of angle "A" of a triangle ABC. If:$b-c = 20$ and $b\cdot c(p - b)(p - c)= 10c$
{$p$ ➔ semiperimeter) (Answer:$1$)
*(It is possible that there is an error in the statement and it is $(b-c)(p-b)(p-c)$. It is not clear whether the sign is multiplication or subtraction in the original image of the question.)

My progress:
[image]

$b - c = 20\\
(bc)(p-b)(p-c)=10c$

Properties:

$AP^2 = mn - bc\\
\frac{AP}{m} = \frac{c}{n}\\
m=\frac{ab}{b-c}\\
n=\frac{ac}{c-b}\\
a^2 = mn-ac\\
AP = \frac{\sqrt{bc(p-b)(p-c)}}{|b-c|}\\
AP =\frac{ \sqrt{10c}}{20}\\
AP^2 = \frac{10c}{400}\\
AP^2 = \frac{c}{40}$

...?

Comment: If $b\cdot c$ then $c$ is trivially simplified and if $b-c$ then   you have trivially as only data $2(p - b)(p - c)= c$. There is a non-trivial typo to be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By external angle bisector formula,

$ \displaystyle AP^2 = bc \left[ \left(\frac{a}{b-c}\right)^2 - 1\right]$

$ \displaystyle  = \frac{bc}{400} \left[ a^2 - (b-c)^2 \right] = \frac{bc}{100} (p-b) (p-c)$

If $ ~bc (p-b)(p-c) = 100, AP = 1$. So I think it should read $100$ instead of $10c$. That seems to be the typo.

Comment: This would probably be the mistake. You are right. Thank you very much